# Rendering has_many in ActiveModelSerializer conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have the following serializers:

```
class V1::CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_one :category_name, :class_name => 'V1::CategoryName'
  has_many :brands, :class_name => 'V1::Brand'
end

class V1::CategoryNameSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name
  has_many :brand_names, :class_name => 'V1::BrandName'
end

class V1::BrandSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_one :brand_name, :class_name => 'V1::BrandName'
end

class V1::BrandNameSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name
end
```

When I render via Category `render json: seller.categories` I do not want the BrandNames to be printed. Output should be something like:

```
{
  "seller_id": 1,
  "categories" :
  [
    {
    "name" : "Washing Machines",
    "brands" : ["LG", "Samsung"]
    }
  ]
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "brands_categories": [
        {
            "category_name": {
                "name": "Washing Machines",
                "brand_names": [
                    {
                        "name": "LG"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Samsung"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "brands": [
                {
                    "brand_name": {
                        "name": "LG"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "brand_name": {
                        "name": "Samsung"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, I want to keep the current behavior of printing `render json: V1::CategoryName.all` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the `CategorySerializer` to

```
class V1::CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :category, :brands

  def category
    object.category_name.name
  end

  def brands
    brand_names = []
    object.brands.each do |brand|
      brand_names << brand.brand_name[:name]
    end
    brand_names
  end
end
```

Comment: I"m about to do the same thing. Is this really the best option? Feels inelegant.

Comment: If the output is fixed in your mind then this is the best. **Most** elegant would be to use the default rails output i.e. without any serializer